# Swift: How can I make UITextView in UITableViewCell firstresponder

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, xcode7, swift2

I have searched (so far unsuccessfully) for an (understandable) solution to this problem. My app uses UITableViews with cells that contain UITextViews. I want to be able to select the UITextView rather than the underlying cell. I understand that I need to make it the firstresponder but cannot find out how to do this. I am using Swift 2.

### Update - my code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)
{
    switch (getTipsInfo(viewName, sectionNumber: indexPath.section, tipOrder: indexPath.row).tipType) {
    case "URL":
        defaults.setObject(getTipsInfo(viewName, sectionNumber: indexPath.section, tipOrder: indexPath.row).tipLinkName, forKey: "URL")
        myStack.push(getViewNC(viewName))
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(browserNC)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case "link":
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        myStack.push(getViewNC(viewName))
        let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(getTipsInfo(viewName, sectionNumber: indexPath.section, tipOrder: indexPath.row).tipLinkName)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        ()
    } // end switch
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to make this `UITextView` the first responder immediately upon it loading, you could put the following code inside of your `awakeFromNib` method inside of a custom `UITableViewCell` class.

```
self.myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This will make it so that the cursor will automatically be inside of `myTextView` whenever this cell loads, and the keyboard will come up as well.

Comment: I do not want to edit the field. I just want to use it to link to another view or browser view. I added your code to the custom cell class but it had no effect.

Comment: So you want to segue from the current view controller when the user taps on the textView?

Comment: Yes. And it works as long as I tap outside of the text area.

Comment: Is the segue connected to the cell, or the textView? Is userInteractionEnabled set to true on the textView? Have you tried hooking the segue to a tapGestureRecognizer that is on the textView?

Comment: My apologies. I don't think I understood your question properly. I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath - is there a didSelectTextView (or equivalent)? I'm still a learner in this area.

Comment: Elsewhere I use a target and selector ... Is this what I should be using here?

Comment: Not a problem, I didn't state it very clearly. The reason that it is going when you tap on the row instead of the textView is because you are using didSelectRowAtIndexPath. This method is called only when the user taps on the cell. If you would like to make it so that it goes when you tap on the textView, then you can use an IBAction that is connected to a UITapGestureRecognizer that is on your UITextView. Then you can use 'performSegueWithIdentifier' inside of the IBAction to go to the new ViewController.

Comment: Yes, you can use a target-action/selector method here

Comment: I never figured out how to get a text view in a table to respond to a tap but I realized that in my app adding a button to each cell would work. I hid the textview and/or button depending upon what I wanted to do. That took me about 5 minutes once I decided it would work for me.